# Cómo modificar intensidades de colores en una imagen con numpy. Python

Tags: python, array, numpy

Tengo la siguiente definición para crear una función que muestre una imagen en escala de grises:

```
def escala_grises(imagen):
''' Transforma una imagen en color a grados de grises

ENTRADA: 
   - imagen: matriz de píxeles -> [[(float, float, float)]]
SALIDA: 
   - matriz de píxeles con la imagen de entrada en escala de grises -> [[float]]

Toma como entrada una matriz de píxeles RGB, y produce como salida una
matriz de píxeles con intensidades en escala de grises (un único valor por
cada pixel).

Para convertir una imagen en color a escala de grises hay que aplicar
los siguientes pesos para integrar los tres canales de color en un único
valor de intensidad:
    - Rojo:  0.2989
    - Verde: 0.5870
    - Azul:  0.1140
'''
```

El argumento `imagen` es una matriz extraída de un archivo ".jpeg" mediante un array. Ej: `[[[82, 119, 171], [91, 128, 180], [85, 122, 174], [84, 121, 173], [88, 125, 177], [84, 121, 173], [84, 121, 173], [85, 122, 174]]]`.

Supongo que es una matriz 3D ya que el método `shape` devuelve `(330, 600, 3)`, el 3 creo que proviene del número de colores presentes en el archivo "RGB".

La pregunta es, cómo modificar el array para que la media de las intensidades de los colores coincidan con `[0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140]`, teniendo en cuenta que solo puedo utilizar los siguientes módulos importados:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

**-Contestación a abulafia respecto a los comentarios**
Al parecer, no debo utilizar `métodos` de la biblioteca `numpy` ya que se supone que no los he dado. Así que intentado recrear lo que me has dicho mediante el siguiente código:

```
filtro = []
for i in imagen:
    for r,g,b in i:
        rojo = r*0.2989
        verde = g*0.5870
        azul = b*0.1140
        numero = [int(rojo + verde + azul)]
        filtro.append(numero)
return filtro
```

Pero da una imagen en blanco con el error:

```
ValueError: Image size of 1x198000 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.
```

Adjunto Test de la función escala de grises y de la función para mostrar la imagen:

```
def test_escala_grises(imagen):
    grises = escala_grises(imagen)
    muestra_imagen(grises, cmap='gray')
    guarda_imagen('../img/grises.jpeg', grises, cmap='gray')

def muestra_imagen(imagen, cmap=None):
    imagen = np.array(imagen, dtype='uint8')
    plt.imshow(imagen, cmap=cmap)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Creo que has entendido mal lo que explica la especificación del principio de tu pregunta. Lo que tienes que hacer es convertir cada componente de 3 números (RGB) en un solo numero. Para ello tienes que multiplicar el primero por 0.2989, el segundo por 0.5870 y el tercero por 0.1140, y _sumar_ los tres. Ya que la suma de esos coeficientes es 1, el resultado va a ser un numero entre 0 y 255 (supongo que tendrás que redondearlo a entero).

Comment: Buenas, soy novato en el uso de la librería numpy. ¿Podrías explicarme cómo multiplicar las componentes por los números?

Comment: Aqui tienes una respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/12201744/1264820 que usa `np.dot()`, que es el producto escalar de vectores. En este caso los "vectores" son las tres componentes (r,g,b) y la lista de coeficientes`[0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140]`

Comment: @abulafia He modificado la pregunta inicial para añadir código y algún que otro error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código que convierte cada pixel a escala de grises es correcto. Pero tienes un error:

- La lista que retornas al final en tu función `escala_grises()` ya no es un array bidimensional, como lo era la imagen de entrada, sino una mera secuencia de pixeles. Debes usar `reshape` para volver a darle la forma bidimensional original pues de lo contrario `plt.imgshow()` no sabrá mostrarla.
- Debes usar el `cmap="Gray_r"` para que use una escala de grises en la que 0 represente negro y 255 blanco (el valor por defecto es al revés).

Corrigiendo estos problemas:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def escala_grises(imagen):
  filtro = []
  for i in imagen:
      for r,g,b in i:
          rojo = r*0.2989
          verde = g*0.5870
          azul = b*0.1140
          numero = [int(rojo + verde + azul)]
          filtro.append(numero)
  # Usamos los valores en imagen.shape para conocer el ancho x alto originales
  # y reformateamos la lista para que use esas dimensiones
  result = np.reshape(filtro, imagen.shape[:2])
  return result


def muestra_imagen(imagen, cmap="Greys_r"):
    # Con el nuevo código no es necesario convertirlo a array numpy
    # pues la función escala_grises ya retorna uno
    # imagen = np.array(imagen, dtype='uint8')
    plt.imshow(imagen, cmap=cmap)
    plt.show()
```

Ejemplo de uso (con la imagen siguiente, sacada de [aqui](http://www.hoax-slayer.com/images/no-bonsai-kitten.jpg))

[image: Imagen de entrada]

```
im = plt.imread("no-bonsai-kitten.jpg", format="jpeg")
grises = escala_grises(im)
muestra_imagen(grises)
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado]

### Actualización

Para que no sea necesario usar `np.reshape()`, el resultado devuelto por `escala_grises()` debería ser una lista de listas, de modo que cada uno de sus elementos represente una fila (con tantos elementos como columnas tenía la imagen original).

El siguiente código implementa esta versión:

```
def escala_grises(imagen):
  result = []  # Esta lista será de "filas"
  for fila in range(imagen.shape[0]):
    aux = []   # Creamos una fila vacia
    for columna in range(imagen.shape[1]):
      pixel = imagen[fila][columna]
      gris = pixel[0]*0.2989 + pixel[1]*0.5870 + pixel[2]*0.1140
      # Añadimos este pixel a la fila
      aux.append(int(gris))
    # Una vez terminada la fila, la añadimos a la lista general
    result.append(aux)
  return result
```

Comment: Gracias, ya he conseguido la imagen en escala de grises y he modificado `cmap` en la función muestra_imagen la cual tenía un error (antes `cmap='cmap'`, ahora `cmap=cmap`) :P. Y tengo otra duda, es posible volver a redimensionar la imagen saliente sin usar métodos de `numpy`, es decir, trabajando con las listas.

Comment: @Jesus_jbs He actualizado la respuesta